# Structuring my collection for fuzzy search for typeahead/autocomplete

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, fuzzy-search

I'm making 3 typeaheads/autocompletes to reduce typos from 3 fields (make, model, owner/user). I have a mongoose collection of assets, like:

```js
const assetsCollection = [
  {
    make: 'Apple',
    model: '17inch MBP 2017',
    owner: 'jim',
    user: 'jim',
    /* many other attributes... */
  },
  {
    make: 'Microsoft',
    model: 'Surface Pro 2',
    owner: 'jim',
    user: 'mike',
    /* many other attributes... */
  },
  {
    make: 'Apple',
    model: '15inch MBP 2020',
    owner: 'jane',
    user: 'mike',
    /* many other attributes... */
  },
]
```

But I DON'T want to return the asset object, I want to return the text of a field. So if my typeahead is for the make field, I want to return only 'Apple', 'Microsoft', etc. Meaning it needs to distinct first.

My present idea is to make 1 collection like below and fuzzy search the `value` attr with `mongoose-fuzzy-searching` plugin or similar. Then run an aggregation query to fill the collection every so many hours or after certain actions. type/value would be unique.

```js
const indexCollection = [
  { type: 'make', value: 'Apple' },
  { type: 'make', value: 'Microsoft' },
  { type: 'model', value: '15inch MBP 2020' },
  { type: 'model', value: '17inch MBP 2017' },
  { type: 'person', value: 'jim' },
  { type: 'person', value: 'jane' },
  { type: 'person', value: 'mike' },
]
```

#### Question:

1. Is there a better structure than pre-indexing to a single collection and searching it? I've also considered 3 seperate collections, but if I wanna do this for more fields, it seems problematic.
2. Is there a better or more maintained library you might recommend for this typeahead/autocomplete?

If it makes any difference, I'm presently using the MUI autocomplete component and Apollo for client and server.

Thank you for any help you can provide!